# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: struct Node<int> * __thiscall Table<int>::find_ptr(int)"

Tags: c++

I'm getting the following errors from my code. Have no idea how to resolve it. Can't locate the problem either.

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: struct Node<int> * __thiscall Table<int>::find_ptr(int)" (?find_ptr@?$Table@H@@QAEPAU?$Node@H@@H@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Table<int>::insert(int const &)" (?insert@?$Table@H@@QAEXABH@Z)
```

Following are my codes:

Following is my link2.h file:

```
#ifndef LINK2_H
#define LINK2_H
#include <stdlib.h> // Provides size_t

template <class Item>
struct Node
{
    Item data;
    Node *link;
};

    // FUNCTIONS for the linked list toolkit
template <class Item>
size_t list_length(Node<Item>* head_ptr);

template <class Item>
void list_head_insert(Node<Item>*& head_ptr, const Item& entry); 

template <class Item>
void list_insert(Node<Item>*& previous_ptr, const Item& entry);

template <class Item>
Node<Item>* list_search(Node<Item>* head_ptr, const Item& target);

template <class Item, class SizeType>

Node<Item>* list_locate(Node<Item>* head_ptr, SizeType position);

template <class Item>
void list_head_remove(Node<Item>*& head_ptr);

template <class Item>
void list_remove(Node<Item>* previous_ptr);

template <class Item>
void list_clear(Node<Item>*& head_ptr);

template <class Item>
void list_copy 
  (Node<Item>* source_ptr, Node<Item>*& head_ptr, Node<Item>*& tail_ptr);

template <class Item>
void list_piece
  (Node<Item>*  source_ptr, Node<Item>*  end_ptr,
   Node<Item>*& head_ptr,   Node<Item>*& tail_ptr);

#include "link2.template"  // Include the implementation
#endif
```

Following is my link2.template file:

```
#include <assert.h>    // Provides assert
#include <stdlib.h>    // Provides NULL and size_t

template <class Item>
size_t list_length(Node<Item>* head_ptr)
// Library facilities used: stdlib.h
{
Node<Item> *cursor;
size_t answer;

answer = 0;
for(cursor = head_ptr; cursor != NULL; cursor = cursor->link)
    answer++;

return answer;
}

template <class Item>
void list_head_insert(Node<Item>*& head_ptr, const Item& new_item)
{
Node<Item> *insert_ptr;

insert_ptr = new Node<Item>;
insert_ptr->data = new_item;
insert_ptr->link = head_ptr;
head_ptr = insert_ptr;


}

template <class Item>
void list_insert(Node<Item>* &previous_ptr, const Item& new_item)
{
Node<Item> *insert_ptr;

insert_ptr = new Node<Item>;
insert_ptr->data = new_item;

insert_ptr->link = previous_ptr->link;
previous_ptr->link = insert_ptr;

}

template <class Item>
Node<Item>* list_search(Node<Item>* head_ptr, const Item& target)
{
Node<Item> *cursor;

for (cursor = head_ptr; cursor != NULL; cursor = cursor->link)
    if (cursor->data == target)
        return cursor;

return NULL;
}

template <class Item, class SizeType>
Node<Item>* list_locate(Node<Item>* head_ptr, SizeType position)
// Library facilities  assert.h, stdlib.h
{
Node<Item> *cursor;
size_t i;

assert(position > 0);

cursor = head_ptr;
for(i = 1; (i != position) && (cursor != NULL); i++)
    cursor = cursor->link;
return cursor;
}

template <class Item>
void list_head_remove(Node<Item>*& head_ptr)
{
Node<Item> *remove_ptr;

remove_ptr = head_ptr;
head_ptr = head_ptr->link;
delete remove_ptr;
}

template <class Item>
void list_remove(Node<Item>* previous_ptr)
{
Node<Item> *remove_ptr;

remove_ptr = previous_ptr->link;
previous_ptr->link = remove_ptr->link;
delete remove_ptr;
}

template <class Item>
void list_clear(Node<Item>*& head_ptr)
// Library facilities used: stdlib.h
{
while (head_ptr != NULL)
    list_head_remove(head_ptr);
}

template <class Item>
void list_copy
(Node<Item>* source_ptr, Node<Item>*& head_ptr, Node<Item>*& tail_ptr)
// Library facilities used: stdlib.h
{
head_ptr = NULL;
tail_ptr = NULL;

// Handle the case of the empty list
if (source_ptr == NULL)
    return;

// Make the head node for the newly created list, and put data in it
list_head_insert(head_ptr, source_ptr->data);
tail_ptr = head_ptr;

// Copy the rest of the nodes one at a time, adding at the tail of new list
for (source_ptr = source_ptr->link; source_ptr != NULL; source_ptr = source_ptr->link)
{
    list_insert(tail_ptr, source_ptr->data);
    tail_ptr = tail_ptr->link;
}
}

 template <class Item>
 void list_piece
 (Node<Item>* start_ptr, Node<Item>* end_ptr, Node<Item>*& head_ptr, Node<Item>*&   tail_ptr)
// Library facilities used: assert.h, stdlib.h
{
head_ptr = NULL;
tail_ptr = NULL;

// Handle the case of the empty list
if (start_ptr == NULL)
    return;

// Make the head node for the newly created list, and put data in it
list_head_insert(head_ptr, start_ptr->data);
tail_ptr = head_ptr;
if (start_ptr == end_ptr)
    return;

// Copy the rest of the nodes one at a time, adding at the tail of new list
for (start_ptr = start_ptr->link; start_ptr != NULL; start_ptr = start_ptr
->link)
  {
    list_insert(tail_ptr, start_ptr->data);
    tail_ptr = tail_ptr->link;
    if (start_ptr == end_ptr) 
        return;
  }
}
```

Following is my table2.h file:

```
#ifndef TABLE_H
#define TABLE_H
#include<cstdlib>
#include"link2.h" // provide list toolkit 

template<class Item>
class Table
{
public:
// TYPEDEF
typedef std::size_t size_type; //synonym for size_t
static const size_type TABLESIZE = 10;

Table();
Table(const Table& source);
~Table();
void operator =(const Table& source);

// CONST Member functions

size_type size() const{ return totalRecords; }
bool is_present(const Item& target) const; 
//   void find(int key, bool& found, RecordType& result) const;

// MODIFICATION Member functions

void insert(const Item& entry);
void remove(int key);
void printTable();



Node<Item> *find_ptr(int key);

private:
size_type totalRecords;
Node<Item> *dataArray[TABLESIZE]; 

//HELPER Functions

std::size_t hash(int key) const;

};
#include "table2.template"
#endif
```

Following is table2 template file:

```
#include "table2.h"
#include "link2.h"
#include<iostream>


template<class Item>
const typename Table<Item>::size_type Table<Item>::TABLESIZE;

template<class Item>  // template class
Table<Item>::Table()
{  

for(size_type i = 0; i < TABLESIZE; i++)
  dataArray[i] = new Node<Item>; //allocate new dynamic memory


 totalRecords = 0;

}/* end constructor */


template<class Item>
Table<Item>::Table(const Table& source) //copy constructor
{
Node<Item>* tail_ptr; // dummy node required for list_copy function

for(size_type i = 0; i < TABLESIZE; i++) 
    dataArray[i] = new Node<Item>; //allocate new dynamic memory if needed

for( size_type i = 0; i < TABLESIZE; i++)
    list_copy(source.dataArray[i], dataArray[i], tail_ptr);
totalRecords= source.totalRecords;
}// end copy constructor 



template<class Item>
Table<Item>::~Table() //removed <RecordType>
{ 
  for(size_type i = 0; i < TABLESIZE ; i++)
    list_clear(dataArray[i]);
  totalRecords= 0;
}//end destructor 



template<class Item>
void Table<Item>::operator =(const Table& source) //removed <RecordType>
{
Node<Item>* tail_ptr; 

if(this == &source) //check for self-assignment
    return;

totalRecords = 0; //reset record before copy

for(size_type i = 0; i < TABLESIZE; i++) 
 {
    list_clear(dataArray[i]); //reset list before Copy
 }

for(size_type i = 0; i < TABLESIZE; i++) 
    dataArray[i] = new Node<Item>; //allocate new dynamic memory if needed


for(size_type i = 0; i < TABLESIZE; i++) 
 {
   list_copy(source.dataArray[i], dataArray[i], tail_ptr);
 }

 totalRecords = source.totalRecords; 
 } 



 template<class Item>
 void Table<Item>::printTable() //removed <RecordType> after Table
 {

 Node<Item> *cursor ; 

 for(size_type i = 0; i < TABLESIZE; i++)
 {

 cursor = dataArray[i];
 std::cout << "[( "<<i<<" )]----> ";

 if(dataArray[i]== NULL)
 {
     std::cout << " NULL" << std::endl;
     continue;
 }

 while(cursor->link != NULL)
 {
     std::cout << "[" << cursor-> data << "]-->";
     cursor = cursor->link;
 }

 if(cursor->link == NULL)
     std::cout << " NULL" << std::endl;
 }
} // end printTable 



template<class Item>
void Table<Item>::insert(const Item& entry) 
{

if( is_present(entry) == false)
{

Node<Item>* cursor;



    cursor = find_ptr(entry);
    if (cursor == NULL)
    {
        list_head_insert(dataArray[hash(entry)],entry);
        ++totalRecords;
    }
    else

        cursor->data = entry;
 }

}



template<class Item>
bool Table<Item>::is_present(const Item& target) const
{
size_type i = hash(target);  
if( list_search(dataArray[i], target) == NULL)
    return false;
else
    return true;
}



template<class Item>
size_t Table<Item>::hash(int key) const
{
return (key % TABLESIZE);
}


 template<class Item>
 Node<Item> Table<Item>::*find_ptr( int key) 
 {
 Node<Item>* cursor ;
 Node<Item>* found ;
 for(size_type i = 0; i < TABLESIZE; i++)
 {
     cursor = dataArray[i];
     if(cursor->link == NULL)
         continue;           
     found = list_search(cursor,key);
         return found;
 }
 return NULL;

}

template<class Item>
void Table<Item>::remove(int key)
{
Node<Item>* cursor;  // dummy cursor node
Node<Item>* target;  // dummy node to be assigned for deletion
bool t = false;             // bool value if key element is found

for( size_type i = 0 ; i < TABLESIZE  && totalRecords >= 0; i++)    
{
    cursor = dataArray[i];  // assign cursor to beginning of each list

    target = list_search(cursor, key); 

      if (target != NULL)       // if target is not NULL, key found
        {

        if (target == dataArray[i]) // if the target is the head of list
        {
            list_head_remove(dataArray[i]); //remove head of list node
            totalRecords--;   //1 less record
            if (totalRecords > TABLESIZE) 
                totalRecords= 0;
        }
        else
        {
            target->data = (dataArray[i]->data); 
            list_head_remove(dataArray[i]); 
            totalRecords--;   //1 less record
            if (totalRecords > TABLESIZE) 
                totalRecords= 0;
        }   

    }

   }
 }
```

Following is my driver file for the program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime> //allows access to time() function
#include"table2.h"
#include "link2.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{

Table<int> first;  //removed <int> template format parameter
Table<int> second;
srand(time(NULL)); // seed rand() function to time of program execution.

//output following messages
cout << "Instantiate two Table objects\n" << endl;
cout << "\t Total records in first Table object " << first.size() << endl;
cout << "\t Contents of first object display at below:" << endl;

first.printTable(); //call object's printTable function to print

cout << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl;
cout << "\t Total records in second Table object " << second.size() << endl;
cout << "\t Contents of second object display at below:" << endl;

second.printTable(); //call object's printTable function to print

cout << "=====================================================" << endl;
cout << "\n\n**random number generator used." << endl;

for (size_t i = 0; i < 70; i++)  // create 70 random numbers for each table
{
    first.insert((rand() % 201)); //random number between 0 ~ 201
    second.insert((rand() % 201)); //also random between 0 ~201
}

cout << "\t Total records in first Table object " << first.size() << endl;
cout << "\t Contents of first object display at below:" << endl;

first.printTable();

cout << "--------------------------------------------------" << endl;
cout << "\t Total records in second Table object " << second.size() << endl;
cout << "\t Contents of second object display at below:" << endl;

second.printTable();

cout << "===========================================" << endl;
cout << "\n\n\n**remove function: remove 1st obj contents .**\n\n" << endl;

for (int k = 0; k <= 200; k++)
{
    first.remove(k);
}

cout << "\t Total records in first Table object " << first.size() << endl;
cout << "\t Contents of first object display at below:" << endl;

first.printTable();

cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl;
cout << "\t Total records in second Table object " << second.size() << endl;
cout << "\t Contents of second object display at below:" << endl;

second.printTable();

cout << "=====================================" << endl;
cout << "\n** Using TBObject1 = TBObject2 . **\n" << endl;

first = second;

cout << "\t Total records in first Table object " << first.size() <<  endl;
cout << "\t Contents of first object display at below:" << endl;

first.printTable();

cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;
cout << "\t Total records in second Table object " << second.size() << endl;
cout << "\t Contents of second object display at below:" << endl;

second.printTable();

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `find_ptr` declared incorrectly.  You have

```
template<class Item>
Node<Item> Table<Item>::*find_ptr( int key)
```

when you want

```
template<class Item>
Node<Item> *Table<Item>::find_ptr( int key)
```

Note the position of the `*` is different.